# exe files size is 0 bytes after download

Tags: c#, download

I am using a webclient to download a C# winform application, all files are fine exept the app.exe, app.exe.config and app.pdb. The size of the files are 0 bytes. On my web hotel the file sizes are fine, but are wrong after download.

this is the code i use to download:

```
private void downloader()
    {
        string desktop = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory);
        if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath))
            System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath);
        WebClient client = new WebClient();

        client.DownloadProgressChanged += new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(client_DownloadProgressChanged);
        client.DownloadFileCompleted += new AsyncCompletedEventHandler(client_DownloadFileCompleted);
        var xdoc = XDocument.Load("http://Mywebsite.Mine/Programs/PatientStorage/update.xml");
        var items = from i in xdoc.Root.Elements("item")
                    select new
                    {
                        Url = (string)i.Element("url"),
                        Name = (string)i.Element("name")
                    };

        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            if (nummer >= urls.Length)
                Array.Resize(ref urls, urls.Length + 1);
            urls[nummer] = item.Url;


            if (nummer >= names.Length)
                Array.Resize(ref names, names.Length + 1);
            names[nummer] = item.Name;

            nummer++;
        }

        var UrlsAndNames = urls.Zip(names, (u, n) => new { urls = u, names = n });

        foreach (var nw in UrlsAndNames)
        {
            AgainConf:
            try
            {
                DateTime startagain = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(1);
                while (DateTime.Now < startagain)
                {
                    this.Refresh();
                    this.Invalidate();
                }
                currentDownload = nw.names;
                client.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(nw.urls), folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath + @"\" + nw.names + "");
                this.Refresh();
                this.Invalidate();
            }
            catch
            { goto AgainConf; }
        }
    }
```

How can it be that my files loose every bit of code? I looked at the file with notepad, and there was no code at all. When i download the app.exe file directly from my web hotel the code is till there, but the application does not show up.

If you need more information, then just tell me. Any help will be appreciated, thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**

The program window now shows up when i download the file directly from the web hotel. I believe it is because something goes wrong when the file is being downloaded through the program that it goes wrong. One strange thing is: when i am using a try catch loop, I recieve no error while downloading the files. Actually, there is an error while downloading ANOTHER file, but that file is intact.

Answer (score 0):

It may be because those files share the same name (with not the same extension).

Comment: all files has an extension and it is like this (app.exe, app.exe.config and app.pdb) I made an edit maby you should read that.